# Evaluate a function in a grid, matlab

Tags: matlab, math, loops, graphics, plot

I want to plot an isosurface of a function ***v***.

Problem is that ***v*** doesn't accept matrix arguments (not vectorizable function as
it contains Laguerre associated polynomials)

So if I create a meshgrid for the values of x,y,l

```
[r,th,l]=meshgrid(0:0.5:5,0:pi/2:2*pi,0:2);

x=r.*cos(th);
y=r.*sin(th);
```

Then I suppose to evaluate ***v*** using loops (counters) as I can not bypass
x , y & l as arguments

But I'm doing something wrong, and as a consequence  I'm not 
evaluating ***v*** in the points of the grid:

```
for l=0:2
k=k+1;
    for r=0:0.5:5
    i=i+1;
        for th=0:pi/2:2*pi
        j=j+1;      


fun1=@(R)4*real(exp(-r.^2-R^2+2*1i*R*l./r).*(r+1i*R).^(2*l).*...
  (mfun('L',n/2-l/2,l,r.^2+R^2)).^2);

v(i,j,k)=integral(fun1,-inf,inf);

        end
    end  
end
```

does someone knows how to do the loops so I can obtain a ***v*** that matches in size with x, y, l so I can use:

isosurface(x,y,l,v) ??

or does someone knows how to obtain the mentioned isosurface ***v*** through an alternative way?

I really need all the help I can get :)

regards,

Pablo

Comment: What do you mean when you say *I'm not evaluating v in the points of the grid*? What exactly is wrong with your output?

Comment: well, it is a very big size compared with the size it is suppose to be, and mostly, its full of zeros